# SSH pubkey auth fails on CentOS 7.9 but not 7.8

Tags: centos, ssh

I have access to a number of servers via ssh. Some of them are running CentOS 7.8.2003 and some are running 7.9.2009. I can connect to the 7.8 servers without issue while I have to use password auth for the 7.9s.

This is the output of `ssh -i .ssh/keyfile centos79` run from `centos79`

```
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/keyfile
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:...
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

`ssh -i .ssh/keyfile centos78` from `centos79` works fine.

`keyfile` matches `ssh -Q key` and `ssh -Q cipher`

My home directory is mounted with `autofs` and shared across all of the servers.

`~` is 755;
`~/.ssh` is 700;
`~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is 600; `~/.ssh/keyfile`is 600

`sshd` reports `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017` on both the 7.8s and the 7.9s.

The parent directory to `~` has `security.selinux (len 30)` on both; it is 755 on both. `~` doesn't have anything in that field.

Running `restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh` didn't help.

I don't have root access to check the config/run debug/check the log... I'm assuming that they're all on pretty much default configs.

Appreciate any insight - thanks!

Edit:
Found the 7.8 servers - they run fine as well, so just 7.9 that's having issues...

Comment: Temporarily disable SELinux on CentOS-7.9 ($ sudo setenforce 0)

Comment: I sadly don't have admin on the server and the admins just tell me to use a password. 
Is there a way to infer what selinux is doing without actually changing it?
Thanks again!

Comment: from CentOS-7.9 what is the output of # ls -ldZ ~./ssh

Comment: ~/.ssh:
 `system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0`

~:
`system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0`

/u (parent folder):
`system_u:object_r:autofs_t:s0`

Comment: Does the output match with one from CentOS-7.8?

Comment: Yeah, all three are the same on the 7.8 server. (Also, sorry, I just realised that I didn't update part of my post when I found the 7.8 servers. The 7.8 servers have the same security.selinux (len 30) on `/u`. The individual user folders don't have anything in that field except for 1 shared folder created by root.)